# Using IN and EXISTS subquery with AND operation instead of OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
create table policies
(
  policyno varchar(15)
);

insert into policies values ('500'),('501'),('502'),('503');

Declare @PolicyNos varchar(1500) = '500|503';    

SELECT * FROM policies
WHERE policyno = ALL(SELECT item from dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|'));
```

User is going to input multiple policies from front end and application sending multiple
policies pipe separated as in @PolicyNos variable.

I'm using split function provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/337752/435559 to check if all policies in @PolicyNos must exists then return true if any one exists but not the other then return false.

I Tried IN and EXISTS but they do OR operation inside but I want AND every policy exists then return true else false.

Edit -- Added In exists code which I tried

```
SELECT * FROM policies
WHERE policyno IN (SELECT item from dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|'));

SELECT * FROM policies
WHERE exists (SELECT item from dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|') where item = policies.policyno);
```

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: @JohnSaunders that is what I tried with ALL in subquery, when I try with ANY it does OR operation.

Comment: You say "IN and EXISTS" - show us the queries with "IN and EXISTS".

Comment: @JohnSaunders You seems to be a school teacher, added code please check.

Comment: Not a school teacher. Just someone spending his time to try to help you, and expecting you to do your part to help yourself.

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend changing the interface. SQL Server has two data types *designed* to contain multiple values - XML and tables. Pipe-delimited strings (or e.g. CSV) are just a bodge when better data types already exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
WITH vals(val) as (
      SELECT item
      FROM dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|')
     )
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT v.val) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.policyno) THEN 'true'
             ELSE 'false'
        END)
FROM vals v left join
     policies p
     ON v.val = p.policyno
```

Comment: I'm checking for all elements existence so inner join would be fine I feel, why Left join?

Comment: @mr_eclair . . . An inner join would filter rows from both tables, so you would not find policies in `vals` that don't match.

Comment: But then it might need to be a full join, or non-matching policies from the input would be ignored (don't know if they should). And then you would probably also need to compare to `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

I might not have quite understood your question but you could find invalid policy codes with

```
SELECT item AS invalidPolicy
FROM dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM policies 
    WHERE item = policies.policyno
)
```

if you need a conditional

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT item AS invalidPolicy
    FROM dbo.fnSplit(@PolicyNos,'|') 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM policies 
        WHERE item = policies.policyno
    )
) BEGIN
     .....
END
ELSE BEGIN
     ......
END
```